# Is there a definable model of PA whose domain is a proper class and whose complete theory is not definable?

Tags: set-theory, peano-arithmetic, definability

Assume ZFC. Is there a formula of $\mathcal{L}_\in$ (without parameters) defining a model $\mathcal{M}$ of PA whose domain is a proper class but the complete theory of that model is not definable by any formula of $\mathcal{L}_\in$ (again without parameters)?

Edit: Instead of model, I should really have said relative interpretation. So I want five formulas $\psi_D(\cdot)$, $\psi_0(\cdot)$, $\psi_1(\cdot)$,$\psi_+(\cdot)$ and $\psi_\times(\cdot)$ to define proper classes M, $0^\mathcal{M}$,$1^\mathcal M$,$+^\mathcal M$ and $\times^\mathcal M$. With some abuse of notation I'll write

$$\mathcal M = \langle M, 0^\mathcal M ,1^\mathcal M ,+^\mathcal M,\times ^\mathcal M \rangle. $$

Then when I say that $\mathcal M $ is a model so PA, I mean that $\varphi^\mathcal M$ for every axiom $\varphi$ of PA.

Comment: I suspect that you can use Easton's theorem to establish that it is consistent for such a thing to happen. Given a model $V$ of ZFC, Easton's theorem implies that for any class $C$ of regular cardinals, there is a class forcing extension $V[G]$ in which for any regular $\kappa$, $2^{\kappa} = \kappa^+$ if and only if $\kappa \in C$. This gives you the ability to (parameter free) definably code an arbitrary class of ordinals into a model of ZFC.

Comment: What this means precisely is that if $V$ is a countable well-founded model of ZFC and $M$ is a countable model of PA, then there's a class forcing extension $V[G]$ which contains a definable isomorphic copy of $M$ whose domain is the ordinals of $V[G]$. The tricky part would be to engineer $M$ so that its theory is not definable in $V[G]$.

Comment: What do you mean by a "model of PA"? How do you state that something is a model of PA if you don't have a satisfaction predicate for it?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek My guess would me that ZFC proves all axioms of PA with quantifiers restricted to $\mathcal M$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Good point. I'll clarify with an edit.

Comment: @JamesHanson Isn't it the case that if the theory of $M$ is not definable in $V$ in the first place, then it cannot be definable in $V[G]$ either (without parameters) because the Easton product is weakly homogeneous? So picking any model whose theory is not definable in $V$ (which there are) would suffice. On the other hand one would need (I think) to ensure that the class forcing is admissible, which is not directly clear to me.

Comment: I guess you could add via class forcing a generic class model of PA, without adding new sets (mimicking upwards Löwenheim-Skolem). In particular the theory of the model is not even a set in this extension. And then code the model as suggested by James. Via my comment, the theory of the model is still not definable without parameters.